# Resizing window contents with lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, window-resize

I'm trying to have the contents of my display resize when the window is resized. Here's my code:

```
        if (Display.wasResized()) {
            this.width = Display.getWidth();
            this.height = Display.getHeight();

            GL11.glViewport(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            GL11.glOrtho(0.0f, this.width, 0.0f, this.height, 1.0f, -1.0f);
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        }
```

When I use this, the window's content don't resize, it just moves towards the origin. Is there any way to make the contents actually resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redraw the scene. OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's "merely" the pencil with which you draw on the paper provided by the OS. Once you've drawn something, OpenGL doesn't remember it.

BTW: You should neither set the viewport size nor the projection matrix in the window resize handler. You do that as preparations in the drawing function, just like clearing the framebuffer.

Comment: @JakeSumrican: Usually you just set a few variables, like width and height. Also if some full window postprocessing is done in the render pipeline you resize the intermediary textures. In short you prepare everything that's influenced by the window's size. But you don't make any calls that draw, or have a direct influence on drawing operations.